# Java Jtable searching

Tags: java, jtable

When I am typing in jtable row I need to get suggestions to that table rows(filtered) from mysql data base and select from it (like  Invoice generating as picture )I need to develop as below picture and here is the code I coded so far 
 jdbc j = new jdbc();
        DefaultTableModel dt = (DefaultTableModel) tab_reta_in.getModel();

```
    int row = tab_reta_in.getSelectedRow();
    int col = tab_reta_in.getSelectedColumn();

    Data_feild = (String) tab_reta_in.getValueAt(row, col);
    int Def_r = row;


    if (col == 0) {

        try {
            ResultSet rs = j.GetData("select * from invoice_retails where name like '" + Data_feild + "%' ");

            while (rs.next()) {

                String col0 = rs.getString("medi_id");
                String col1 = rs.getString("name");
                String col2 = rs.getString("prize");

                Object[] rows = {col0, col1, col2};
                dt.addRow(rows);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
```

Comment: Please add what have you done so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: A like query is what you kinda need, but can't say anything specific without looking at the code you've written.